# How do I prove that there is no strictly monotonically increasing arithmetic sequence in which all elements are primes?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does anyone have an idea on how to prove this?

"There is no strictly monotonically increasing arithmetic sequence in which all elements are primes."

Any help appreciated!
Thanks:)

Comment: Well, write what it means to be a monotonically increasing arithmetic sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, and $k$ divides $p(n)$, then $k$ divides $p(mk+n)$ for any $m$.

In particular, this applies to $p$ a linear polynomial. Now note that terms in arithmetic progression are the consecutive values of a linear polynomial with integer coefficients: $a,a+b,a+2b,\dots$ are $p(0),p(1),\dots$ for $p(x)=a+xb$.

Comment: That sounds good, but how do I know that there is an element in the sequence that's equal to p(mk + n)?

Comment: The $(mk+n)$-th member of the sequence is is $p(mk+n)$.

Comment: In case you are confused about this: For any $N$, no matter how large, [there is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem) a strictly increasing arithmetic progression of length $N$ consisting solely of primes. The question is about infinite sequences, so no matter how large $k,n,m$ are, the sequence has an $(mk+n)$-th term.

Comment: Okay, it's clear now thanks, I just couldn't put the existence of element and that k divides it together:) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the first term in the sequence is prime $p$. Then the $(p+1)$th term in the sequence is $p + pn$ for some positive integer $n$, since by assumption your sequence must be all integer-valued if it's all prime. Can this term $p + pn$ be prime?

Comment: @nitrogenhurricane, in this answer the difference between two elements is $n$, not $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the arithmetic sequence $a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d,\dots$. The sequence is increasing, so for some $k$ we have $a+kd\gt 1$.

Now consider $(a+kd)+ (a+kd)d$. This is in the sequence, for
$$(a+kd)+(a+kd)d= a+(k+a+kd)d.$$
But $(a+kd)+(a+kd)d$ is not prime, since it is clearly divisible by $a+kd$, and greater than $a+kd$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as Andres was faster I think, so it's fair to accept his. Please anyone correct me if I'm wrong since I'm a newbie here.

Comment: In my opinion the solution by user2566092 is much cleaner and better. Mine is essentially the same, but hides the simplicity of the idea. So I think you should *not* accept mine.

Comment: You should accept whichever answer you think best answers the question. It's okay for this to be a late answer (it's even okay to change your mind)